# Multiclass logistic regression update algorithm

Tags: logistic, matlab, nonlinear-regression, multinomial-distribution, logit

My question pertains to section 2, called "Multi-class Logistic regression", of this [pdf](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~xfern/classes/cs534/notes/logistic-regression-note.pdf), especially the update rules. (The entire section is only a couple of paragraphs.)

Everything seems to make sense, but I don't see how one is supposed to implement the gradient ascent algorithm.

- What is $y_i^k$? What are its dimensions?
- What is the dimension of the weights?
- What is $x_i$? Say you have a matrix where each row is an observation and each column is a feature. What would $x_i$ be? Is it a row?
- Is $p(k|x_i)$ the same thing as $p(y = k|x)$ for a particular observation?

Side note: I'm trying to implement a simple multi-class logistic regression in MATLAB.

Comment: Be wary of any field that invents new names for old ideas or that claims that logistic regression is a classifer.  The proper terms for what you are seeking are polytomous logistic regression or multinomial logistic regression.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $Y$ is a multiclass output of dim $N \times 1$, i.e., the $i^{\rm th}$ row of $Y$, denoted $y_i$ can take values in $\{1,2,\ldots,K\}$.  Since the author is using 1-of-K coding, $y_i^k = 1$ if $y_i = k$ and $0$ otherwise.

You also have feature matrix $X$ dim $N \times P$.  The weight matrix ${\bf w_k}$ will be of dimension $(P + 1) \times 1$ where the $+ 1$ is for an intercept and will correspond to the $k^{\rm th}$ regression  $\rightarrow p(y = k | x)$.  Based on the notes, $x_i$ is the $i^{\rm th}$ row of $X$.